# Attempting to print in IE 8 raise a error: dialogArguments.__IE_PrintType

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, activex

i am attempting to print a html page in a new explorer window in a transparent way. I know is very ugly but i am using this js:

```
function print(elem) {
        if (IE) {
            var browser=new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            var form=elem.form;
            var href=window.location.href;
            browser.Navigate2(href+
                    "?param1="+form.field1.value+
                    "&param2=value2");
            /* OLECMDID values:
            * 6 - print
            * 7 - print preview
            * 1 - open window
            * 4 - Save As
            */
            while (browser.Busy||browser.ReadyState!=4) {};
            browser.ExecWB(6,1);
            browser.Quit()
        } else alert (NO_IE);
    }
```

Ok the strange thing is that when i put a debug break point and simply continue this monster works but if not ie raise a error:

Line: 291
Character: 1
Error: 'dialogArguments.___IE_PrintType' is null or is not a object.
Code: 0
URL: res://ieframe.dll/preview.js

Any idea about the cause of that????
I tried with browser.ExecWB(6,2); too
Thanks!!!

Comment: From what I remember there is a window.print() function you could use instead.

Comment: Yep it's my alternative but one of the requirements was the printing should be transparent for the user, is there any way to reach this with window.print()?